# Retrieve login data from mysql database and redirect to a page according to the login data matched with

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mysql, css

```
<script type="text/javascript" language=javascript>


function check(login)/*function to check userid & password*/
{
    /*the following code checkes whether the entered userid and password are matching*/
    if (login.userNameTextBox.value == "name" && login.passWordTextBox.value == "pass") {
        window.open('ViewUser.htm')/*opens the target page while Id & password matches*/
    }
    else {
        alert("Error Password or Username")/*displays error message*/


    }
}
```

The above code currently has a hard coded userid and password, but i need to retrieve that data from MySql database. Please help, i know my question may be redundant but please me.

Comment: Need to use jquery ajax if want to interact with database. Many tutorials u can find on web

Comment: use php to get values from sql then do your validation

Comment: @Sridhar I have strict limitation of the languages to use. I dont know how to connect to the mysql database in html, because it is said that HTML doesn"t have the capability(unless if am mistaken).

Comment: HTML are markup languages, basically they are set of tags like `<html>, <body>`, which is used to present a website using css, and javascript as a whole. All these, happen in the clients system or the user you will be browsing the website.

Now, Connecting to a database, happens on whole another level. It happens on server, which is where the website is hosted.

So, in order to connect to the database and perform various data related actions, you have to use server-side scripts, like `php, jsp, asp.net` etc.

Comment: Thank you for the input, I have just found out that I am required to use  Java API for a RESTful web service, for exposing the data.